# Computers can't find each other on LAN with Avahi

Tags: ubuntu, networking, lan, mdns

I have two computers plugged into a Comcast router. One is running Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop, the other, Ubuntu 10.10 Server.

Both have Avahi installed and running. However, when I run `avahi-browse`, each computer only displays itself.

I "theoretically" have mDNS correctly set up according to a number of guides, however, it doesn't do any good because the computers can't find each other.

Is it possibly an issue relating to the router? A similar setup works fine with my desktop and laptop over the WiFi at home, but for some reason these computers won't find each other on the LAN.

Comment: it's easy to point the finger at buggy firmware...i have no idea, so that's where i go

Answer (score 1):

1. When you have your nic's configured by DHCP, check if they get an ip adres, and if yes, what are the ip adresses (please post, incl subnet and gateway and please post the LAN settings for your router, IP scope, subnet and gateway)
2. Have you pingt one or the other? ie: ping 192 .168.1.3 from 192.168.1.4 or visa versa
3. I'm not sure if Unbuntu works with network workgroups, but if they do, are they in the same workgroup?

If you can ping both computers from both computers, your only a few steps away from a working home network, if not... goto 4

4. Be sure that there isn't a firewall or antivirus software blocking connections.
5. Does the router have a inbuilt firewall? Could this block any nic's or connections?

Also you said, it works with WIFI, I'm thinking about some permission isseus